# Unable to add Meeting Room while setting up meeting on Shared Calendar

Tags: exchange, microsoft-outlook-2016

I tried to add a meeting room to the meeting and I could see them. But when they are selected, the outlook "refreshes" and again the option is empty.

the interesting thing is that when I add users to the meeting, it works and I can choose a room. The question is why it does not work if no one was invited to the meeting?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQJfq.png)

Comment: When testing on my side, I can add the room before adding attendees. Do you click Rooms to select rooms? What if we directly type the room names?
We can create a new profile: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-Outlook-profile-f544c1ba-3352-4b3b-be0b-8d42a540459d

Comment: No, when i trying to select room it dissapear after a few seconds. I have to add attendee to "hold it "

Comment: If no profile doesn't work, we can try opening Outlook in safe mode to see if the issue continues. Please exit Outlook, press Win key + R to open the Run command, type outlook.exe /safe and then press Enter. This helps eliminate whether the problem lies on any third party add-ins.